Losing line break when creating HTML Email
I'm using Apps Script to try and create an automated report from Sheets. The email is to pull in a simple table which consists of a header row of working days in the week, then a second row which contains a list of names which are absent on 'x' day. This list contains information condensed from other formulas: =TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10), TRUE, C8:C15).
I've tried following this guide and adapting to my needs: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r-g73gCpS4o
I'm almost there and can get the table in my email however the CHAR(10) is lost in the process and destroying the formatting of the table.
I've got the following files. I assume the issue / resolution will have to be in my dataCollector.gs file:
Code.gs
function myFunction() {

// connect to html template
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("email");

// make data collection available to html files
  html.dataCollect = dataCollector(1800699589);

// connect to the template so we can send it in email
  var emailConnect = html.evaluate().getContent();

// send email
  GmailApp.sendEmail(
    ["EXAMPLE EMAIL 1","EXAMPLE EMAIL 2"],
    "Planned Absence - Next Week",
    "Please see .....",
    {htmlBody: emailConnect}
    
    )

}

dataCollector.gs
function dataCollector(sheet_id){

  // access the workbook
    var wb = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // access all sheets in workbook
   var sheets = wb.getSheets();

  // loop through sheets
  for(i in sheets){

    // conditional to evaluate the sheet ids

    if(sheets[i].getSheetId() == sheet_id){

      //identify the sheet name
      var sheetName = sheets[i].getSheetName();

    }
  } 

  // access the sheet
    var dataSheet = wb.getSheetByName(sheetName);

  // access the data range
    var dataRange = dataSheet.getRange(1,1,3,5).getDisplayValues()

  // return statement
    return dataRange;

}

email.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('css').getContent(); ?>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Hello, this is email</p>

    <table>
      
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th><?= dataCollect[1][0] ?></th>
          <th><?= dataCollect[1][1] ?></th>
          <th><?= dataCollect[1][2] ?></th>
          <th><?= dataCollect[1][3] ?></th>
          <th><?= dataCollect[1][4] ?></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><?= dataCollect[2][0] ?></td>
          <td><?= dataCollect[2][1] ?></td>
          <td><?= dataCollect[2][2] ?></td>
          <td><?= dataCollect[2][3] ?></td>
          <td><?= dataCollect[2][4] ?></td>
        </tr>

      </tbody>

    </table>

  </body>
</html>


I've tried to use .replace(/n, <br>) on my variable dataRange. Replace does not work unless it is converted to a string.
I tried converting it to a string and then using .replace and I end up losing the entire table and just get two letters showing in my email.
Screenshot of the sheets page to help understand:
Screenshot of the email results:

Are you aware that newline uses a backslash escape, not a forward slash, and is \n not /n? When used in a string the backslash itself has to be escaped to become "\\n"

@Tom Hynes, could you please provide a minimal reproducible example so we can better understand what’s included in This list contains information condensed from other formulas: =TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10), TRUE, C8:C15)

See also: Line break in HTML with '\n'.

I've added screenshots showing the sheet and the email results. I apologise as I'm really out of my depth with this but from the email screenshot you can see I'm very close to getting the desired result. I see a lot of information on adding line breaks, I think the issue I'm dealing with specifically is that I need the line breaks translated from the data within my cells (A3:E3).

Tom, As @StephenP said, .replace("\\n", "<br />")

@TheMaster thank you, can you explain to me exactly where that would go in my scripts?

For eg, String(dataCollect[1][0]).replace("\\n", "<br />") instead of dataCollect[1][0]

This results in no change to the email. But thank you, I did not know to be using 'replace' in the email.html file. I'm trying variations of your suggestion and getting mixed results between either no change or getting "" as text in the email.

I think I found a solution for this, @TomHynes you just wanted the result of the email with new lines if I'm not mistaken.

@LimeHusky thank you, it looks great. Unfortunately when adding to my script it seems to break my datacollector function. I'm going to keep trying to understand what has gone wrong, but very optimistic having seen your results.
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getRange')

@TomHynes there seems to be a problem with your getRange() have you tried changing the datacollector? from dataCollector(0) to dataCollector(1800699589).

@LimeHusky Ahh, I had replaced it in the instance which was from my original code however I had not added for the next three times it was used. Thank you very much! This works exactly as needed, now I can get to work on formatting.

@TomHynes If this answers your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon) and upvoting the answer.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. how to accept the answer

Adding Break Line in HTML
Using <br> is correct and I tried using this line of code .replace("\\n", "<br />") to get the result there seems to be an error. I added some lines of code in your Code.gs and Email.html script.
Sample Data:

Code.gs
function myFunction() {

  // connect to html template
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("email");

  // make data collection available to html files
  html.dataCollect = dataCollector(0);

  // Sets the days to remove the CHAR(10) in each names in day
  let days = []

  // Nested for loop.
  for (let i = 0; i < dataCollector(0)[2].length; i++) {
    if (!dataCollector(0)[2][i]) {
      days.push([])
    } else {
      const tempData = dataCollector(0)[2][i].split("\n");
      let day = [];
      for (let o = 0; o < tempData.length; o++) {
        day.push(tempData[o]);
      }
      days.push(day);
    };
  }
  html.day = days;

  // connect to the template so we can send it in email
  var emailConnect = html.evaluate().getContent();

  // send email
  GmailApp.sendEmail(
    ["sample@email.com", "sample@email.com"],
    "Planned Absence - Next Week",
    "Please see .....",
    { htmlBody: emailConnect })
}

email.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <?!= HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('css').getContent(); ?>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Hello, this is email</p>

    <table>
      
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th><?= dataCollect[1][0] ?></th>
          <th><?= dataCollect[1][1] ?></th>
          <th><?= dataCollect[1][2] ?></th>
          <th><?= dataCollect[1][3] ?></th>
          <th><?= dataCollect[1][4] ?></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
     <tr>
        <? for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) { ?> 
          <td>
            <? for (let o = 0; o < day[i].length; o++) { ?>
              <?= day[i][o] ?><br>
            <? } ?>
          </td>
        <? } ?>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>

Before Result:

After Result:

Reference:

Line Break <br>
Nested For Loop


Offtopic: Request for reviewing synonyms: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/synonyms
